# Why isn't this working to remove duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was working with MySQL, but now I am trying to do similar things with MS SQL (2016) but the query isn't working. I have the table "TEST", and I am trying to remove the duplicates based on the columns "lastname, firstname" matching.

Using the lowest ID value:

```
DELETE FROM TEST
WHERE lastname NOT IN (
  SELECT t.id FROM ( 
    SELECT MIN(PersonID) id
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY lastname, firstname
  ) t
)
```

The columns are: "PersonID" "LastName" "FirstName" "Address" "City"

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'JOHN' to data type int.

Comment: Sorry! The error is as follows:

**Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'JOHN' to data type int.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep the row with the minimum id right? Use `EXISTS`:

```
delete t from test t
where exists (
  select 1 from test
  where firstname = t.firstname and lastname = t.lastname
  and id < t.id
)
```

Comment: Yes, as in the first one to show up should be the one to stay.  I am getting **"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 't'."**. I don't completely understand why.

Comment: Did you change to: `delete t from test t`?

Comment: You're right, this works and I understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the lastname to the ID, hence the error you reported **"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'JOHN' to data type int"** try this instead:

```
DELETE FROM TEST
WHERE PersonID NOT IN (
  SELECT t.id FROM ( 
    SELECT MIN(PersonID) id
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY lastname, firstname
  ) t
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, I recommend using window functions for this:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname order by id) as seqnum
      from test t
     ) 
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: This definitely works, but I'm not versed enough with SQL Server to fully understand it. Is this a more efficent approach to say, how Forpas was doing it? Thank you!

Comment: @Natsu . . . That is an interesting question.  You would need to test it on your data.  In general, I think it would be faster, but under some circumstances, the `exists` clause could be.

Comment: It won't let me vote your response up becaue I'm still new, I'm sorry. I appreciate your help greatly though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting your ID into varchar/nvarchar since the `lastname` is a character. Though you may double check if you should be referring to the PersonID or lastname.

```
DELETE FROM TEST
WHERE lastname NOT IN (
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),t.id) FROM ( 
    SELECT MIN(PersonID) id
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY lastname, firstname
  ) t
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach too :

```
DELETE T2 FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        MIN(PersonID) id
    FROM 
        TEST
    GROUP BY 
        lastname, firstname
  ) t
INNER JOIN TEST T2 ON t.id = T2.PersonID
```